# javascript value coming up empty not sure how to handle it

Tags: javascript

```
function updategeneral() {
    //tmp = "fine_" + tmp + "_";
    var actual = doc.findItem("1speed").value;
    var posted = doc.findItem("2speed").value;
    amt = "";
    if (1speed != "" && 2speed != "") {
        var a = 1 * 1speed;
        var b = 1 * 2speed;
        if (a - b <= 9) {
            alert(amt);
            amt = doc.getDefault("general_spb_1_to_15");
        } else if (a - b <= 15) {
            amt = doc.getDefault("general_spb_16_to_25");
        } else if (a - b <= 25) {
            amt = doc.getDefault("general_spb_15_to_19");
        } else if (a - b <= 29) {
            amt = doc.getDefault("general_spb_26+");
        }
        doc.findItem("mcare_amount").value = amt;
        alert(doc.findItem("mcare_amount").value = amt);
    }
}
```

Default values are:

```
general_spb_1_to_15=30.00 || general_spb_16_to_25=40.00 || general_spb_26+=50.00
```

My problem is when amt is empty or 0 it is always going to `general_spb_1_to_15=30.00`. I am not sure how to fix this- can someone please help? The values that I am using are `1speed = 20` and `2speed = 25` which is negative or empty.

Comment: umm. what is `1speed` and `2speed`? Variables can't start with numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your browser engine is interpreting `1speed` and `2speed` as variables (some will, some won't -- variable names aren't supposed to start with numbers so it would probably be wise to replace these with `speed1` and `speed2`)...

But assuming that, then the case that you describe is seeing a value of `a - b` = `-5` when processing your if statements, which means that it is being caught by

```
if (a - b <= 9) {
   alert(amt);
   amt = doc.getDefault("general_spb_1_to_15");
}
```

To change the result you are getting, you should add another option to the `if` statement structure. Perhaps:

```
if (b > a)
{
     //do something for this special case
} else if (a - b <= 9) {
     alert(amt);
     amt = doc.getDefault("general_spb_1_to_15");
} else if ...
```

You may also want to specifically handle the case where one or both of `speed1`/`speed2` are empty as an else on the outer `if` block.